# Python Cookbook recipe9.14 Discussion

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, metaclass

When I read Python Cookbook recipe 9.14 discussion, it says that I have to convert the OrderedDict to a dict instance when making the final class object. Do I have to do that or using OrderedDict is ok?

I tried this, pass OrderedDict to type constructor, it doesn't raise any exception

```
class OrderedMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attr_dict):
        order = []
        for name, value in attr_dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, Typed):
                value._name = name
                order.append(name)
        attr_dict['_order'] = order
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attr_dict)

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(cls, clsname, bases):
        return OrderedDict()
```

code from book

```
class OrderedMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attr_dict):
        d = dict(attr_dict)
        order = []
        for name, value in attr_dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, Typed):
                value._name = name
                order.append(name)
        d['_order'] = order
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, d)

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(cls, clsname, bases):
        return OrderedDict()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz2qE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not needed.

`type.__new__` can take any mapping - maybe even with fewer methods than the full mapping procotocol - `__iter__`, `__len__` and  `__getitem__` should suffice.

This is likely valid since Python 3.0 - the author of the recipe simply took a "safe road" as he was not sure what might ensue with a non-native dict being passed to `type.__new__` and calling `dict` on the OrderedDict is a plain line of code anyway.

But it would not have made much sense to allow any custom mapping to be used in `__prepare__` and then do not accept that same mapping on `type.__new__` - That is, you don't even need a `__new__` method on your metaclass if all you need is a custom mapping - just the `__prepare__` method.

That said, this particular recipe is now obsolete anyway, as since Python 3.6 dictionaries used in class construction are ordered by default (and as of Python 3.7, all Python dictionaries are ordered by default).

Comment: thanks, you put it very clear, would you mind take a look at another question of mine?[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391827/is-there-any-method-like-init-subclass-before-python-3-6)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that, for some reasons that David Beasley did not elaborate on further than saying that

> "it may cause problems if you don't"

in his [2013 tutorial Python 3 Metaprogramming](https://youtu.be/sPiWg5jSoZI?t=5400), at around 1 Hour and 30 minutes.

Since that tutorial, python 3.6 introduced dictionaries that retain their order, you can therefore, probably, safely ignore the use of an `ordereddict` for this recipe.

Comment: thanks, as for as I watch the video, He didn't prove that not using proper dictionary will cause the program to crash or any error message, the exact time is 1:35:25, again, thank you for answering my question