# Is there any method like __init_subclass__() before python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

When I read Python Cookbook 3rd Edition recipe 9.18, I ran into a class definition with parent Class and some optional argument, and I looked it up. I know that Python 3.6 added a new feature `__init_subclass__()` method for parent class, but the book is written based on Python 3.3, so what method will take these arguments other than a `metaclass`?

The class definition is here:

```
class Spam(Base, debug=True, typecheck=False):
    ...
```

I know that metaclass can accept other optional arguments in its' `__prepare__`, `__new__`, `__init__` method, but `Base` is a parent class, where do these arguments go?

Comment: [PEP 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/#id14) gives a pure-python implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The `__init_subclass__` is an addition to Python 3.6 to reduce the need for custom metaclasses, as many of its uses are "overkill". 
The idea is that each subclass that is created for a (normal, non-meta) base-class that contains an `__init_subclass__` method, it willbe called, with the new subclass as first parameter:

```
class Base:
   def __init_subclass__(subclass, debug=None, typecheck=None, **kwargs):
        # do stuff with the optional debug and typecheck arguments
        # Pass possible arguments not consumed here to superclasses, if any:
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
```

And there is no need for a metaclass at all - the `__prepare__`, `__init__` and `__new__` of the default metaclass - `type` - will ignore any named argument passed in this way. But the default `__init_subclass__` in object will raise if unknown named arguments reach it - the pattern above will consume these arguments, removing them from kwargs. If you are dealing with unknown named arguments, just process kwargs like a normal dictionary - no need for explicit named parameters in the `__init_subclass__`.

Answer (score 1):

They go to the metaclass's `__prepare__` method, just like always. Just because `Base` hasn't specified a metaclass doesn't mean it doesn't have one. The default metaclass is `type`.

The addition of `__init_subclass__` to `type` in Python 3.6 just saves you the effort of defining a custom metaclass in order to implement an equivalent to `__init_subclass__` yourself.